# Changing index of summation

Tags: summation, index-notation

How do you go from $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{-n-1}$ to $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} z^{n}$ ?? It's really confusing.

Comment: Replace the $n$ in the right side by $k$ and see that $k=-n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3} z^{-n-1}
$$

Define $m=-n-1$. $n=0$ gives $m=-1$ and as $n$ goes up by $1$, m goes down by 1. So a $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$ becomes $\sum^{-1}_{-\infty}$ (Slight abuse of notation)

$$
\sum_{-\infty}^{-1} \frac{1}{3} z^{m}
$$

Then rename $m$ to $n$.

Comment: This seems logic but just to make sure, does $\sum_{-1}^{-\infty} z$ = $\sum_{\infty}^{-1} z$ ?

Comment: Be careful that both sides make sense as numbers. In the case you commented, you're getting each side as $\infty$.

Comment: but in general, for any function $z$ is that true? Note that in the second summation there is supposed to be an $-\infty$

Answer (score 0):

Simply observe that for

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{-n-1} $$

when $n$ goes from $0 \to \infty$ the exponent $n-1$ goes form $-1 \to -\infty$ then the identity follows.